# No display after installation of graphics card

Tags: display, graphics-card, motherboard, bios

My desktop motherboard is [XFX Geforce 9300](http://xfxstorage.com/Support/Manuals/9300/9300.pdf). It has one x16 bus PCI Express port. It's working perfectly okay. Few days back I installed a [Gigabyte ATI Radeon HD 5670](http://www.amd.com/en-gb/products/graphics/desktop/5000/5670) graphics card. It was working okay until suddenly yesterday I was getting no display in the monitor. Motherboard has debug LEDs and it was showing code `2A` - according to the manual which means

> Initialize onboard devices. Load Option ROM (VGA and RAID
>   option ROM) form BIOS to memory.

I couldn't find a way to do this. Some post in internet suggested to restart motherboard by taking out the motherboard battery and replacing it after about 10 minutes. I did that it surprisingly it worked. Sadly after sometime the monitor went out again while running it's debug code is appearing again `2A` when I made a force restart. Now I am befuddled again. What can possibly be the problem and how can I solve it? Motherboard manual says `Initialize onboard devices. Load Option ROM (VGA and RAID option ROM) form BIOS to memory.` How can I do it? I have no idea. Is there anyone who can help me out?

Comment: Do you at least get the initial screen once you powered on your machine? Or the Total display has gone?

Comment: No, total display gone.

Comment: Then possibly this could you a hardware conflict between the video card with inbuilt adapter. You need to check with the vendor for further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you it failed while trying to "Load Option ROM (VGA and RAID option ROM) from BIOS to memory". It's not telling you to load anything. :)

Things to try:

- Update your motherboard's firmware (BIOS/UEFI) to the latest available.
- Ensure your power supply can supply enough power for the system with the new video card (ATI recommends at least a 400W power supply for a system with that card installed, but you may need higher depending on what other devices/adapters you have in the computer).
- Consider that your new video card is faulty and replace it.

Comment: My power supply is 420W, and I have running -
1) core 2 duo 2.93 GHz processor
2) two 2GB DDR2 RAMs
3) one 500GB HDD
4) One graphics card as explained above
Ain't 420W enough for these devices?

Just for the curiosity, if video card is faulty then how did I get display for sometime?